# Using elasticsearch registered search templates is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I created a search template using kibana as follows:

```
Post _scripts/mytemplateid3
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "author":  "{{query_string}}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I ran a GET request like the following and it worked ok:

```
GET /spo-demo/_search/template
{
  "id": "mytemplateid3", 
  "params": {
    "query_string": "Annie"
  }
}
```

And the output looks like this:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.9808291,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "spo-demo",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "fTR_pHkB4DiV7smmisqK",
        "_score" : 0.9808291,
        "_source" : {
          "displayurl" : "url1",
          "author" : "Annie Martinez",
          "totalUsers" : "2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So far so good, then I decide to use the search template in my java code like this, but for some reason I am not getting any results. That query should return one hit (same as when I execute the get method in kibana) but it is returning zero hits:

```
        SearchTemplateRequest request = new SearchTemplateRequest();
        request.setRequest(new SearchRequest("spo-demo"));

        request.setScriptType(ScriptType.STORED);
        request.setScript("mytemplateid3");

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("field", "query_string");
        params.put("value", "Annie");
        params.put("size", 5);
        request.setScriptParams(params);

        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new 
         HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")));

        SearchTemplateResponse response = client.searchTemplate(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        SearchResponse searchResponse = response.getResponse();
        SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();
```

Any idea why it is not working in Java even when it works in kibana? What am I missing?

Below my index mappings if anyone is interested:

```
{
  "spo-demo" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "author" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "displayurl" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "totalUsers" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also if I define the template inline (in the java code) it works:

```
request.setScriptType(ScriptType.INLINE);
        request.setScript(
                "{" +
                        "  \"query\": { \"match\" : { \"{{field}}\" : \"{{value}}\" } }," +
                        "  \"size\" : \"{{size}}\"" +
                        "}");

        Map<String, Object> scriptParams = new HashMap<>();
        scriptParams.put("field", "query_string");
        scriptParams.put("value", "Annie");
        scriptParams.put("size", 5);
        request.setScriptParams(scriptParams);

        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")));
        
        SearchTemplateResponse response = client.searchTemplate(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        BytesReference source = response.getSource();
```

Comment: What error do you get when you say "it is not working"?

Comment: While executing the java code It should return one hit and it is returning zero hits.

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to fix this. It seems like I misread the following Elasticsearch documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search-template.html#_registered_templates:

As I mentioned in the question I created the following search template

```
Post _scripts/mytemplateid3
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "author":  "{{query_string}}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While reading the documentation I thought I needed to set the parameters as follow:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("field", "query_string");
params.put("value", "Annie");
```

Instead I was supposed to set them like this:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("field", "author");
params.put("query_string", "Annie");
```

I thought "value" was a reserved word and that was not the case. "value" was just the name that was provided in the documentation sample.